# analytical form for extreme points of polynomial on intervals.

Tags: polynomials, convex-hulls

Given coefficient $w_0, w_1, \cdots w_d$ of d degree polynomial $f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^d w_ix^i$.

And some interval $x \in [x_1, x_2] \subset \mathbb{R}$, I'm interested in the extreme points of this convex set: $CH(\{(x, f(x))| x \in [x_1, x_2]\})$. And here $CH$ is the convex hull operation.

I'm wondering if there is any analytical form to enumerate all the extreme points.

Would $\{x|f'(x)=0 \} \cap [x_1, x_2] \cup \{ x_1, x_2\}$ this be the set of $x$ axis for extreme points?

Comment: The picture you posted doesn't seem to correspond to the [usual definition of convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull). In particular, I don't quite see what the point $A$ and the straight lines crossing at $C$ have to do with the convex hull, if the curve under investigation is $x^2-5$ in $[-\sqrt{5},\sqrt{5}]$. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Thanks! you are right, my picture is misleading, let me delete them. but the question itself is still  valid right?

Comment: Once we agree on the definitions, your question does make sense, evidently. Though, I'm not very optimistic about a satisfactory answer... If nobody else has reacted to your question in the meantime, I will post later (in an hour or so, and temporarily) an extended comment in the answer section with some screenshots to explain what I mean by that.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, this isn't meant to be an answer, this is more like an extended comment.

I'll take as an example $f(x) = x^{3}-x^{2}-x+1$ considered in the interval $[-1,1]$.

[image]

The convex hull of the curve is orange-shaded. The definition of extreme points of the convex hull is simply that they are points that are not on any line segment between other points of the convex hull. For our example, we get

[image]

The set of extreme points is $\{ (x,f(x)) | -1 \leqslant x \leqslant 0 \} \cup (1,0)$

Generally speaking, we have

- $(x_1,f(x_1))$ and $(x_2,f(x_2))$ are always members of the set of extreme points (in this context).
- if the second derivative doesn't change signs over the $[x_1,x_2]$ interval, then $f$ is either convex or concave and the set of extreme points is the entire curve over that interval. As a corollary, for polynomials of degree $2$, this is the case for all $x_1,x_2$.

Things get "hairy" when the segment contains both convex and concave portions. Following example is for $g(x) = x^{4}+x^{3}-x^{2}-x+1$ considered around $[-3/2, 1]$

[image]

The point I want to make here, is that the common tangent does not touch the curve at stationary points (grey points) of the curve (as you seem to have hoped). And from a general point of view, it seems hard to avoid ODEs on a case-by-case basis in order to make an exact determination for the set of extreme points of the convex hull of the curve.

I'd be delighted if I'm wrong, but for now, I don't see a path to a general analytical form.